# What does it mean if the change of volume of a linear transformation is -1?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra, projection

Let $P:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ be projection onto the line with equation $x + 2y = 0$. Find $\det(P)$.

When computing the previous problem, I find that the change of volume is $-1$, however, the determinant is technically $0$ because the linear transformation maps everything to a line that has no volume.

Comment: What do you mean by the "change of volume" being $-1$ in this case, if not the determinant?

Comment: I phrased it as the "change of volume" because I calculated the change of volume of the unit n-cube before and after the 'P' transformation. In order words, you can technically say the determinant.

Comment: But the volume of the $n$-cube (or square) is *not* multiplied by $-1$ when we apply the $P$ transformation. It is multiplied by $0$, since everything maps to a line.

Comment: So then are you not allowed to use the Vol(P(C_n)) method to find the Vol Change of P because you already know that everything maps to a line so that there will not be any volume?

Comment: I am saying that if you do use that method, you also don't get an answer of $-1$. I am trying to understand exactly what calculation you did that gave you $-1$ as an answer.

Comment: Ah, I see, as long as I'm not supposed to get -1 that's ok. That's everything I needed to hear, I'll go and revise my computation until I get the correct answer.